# C++ coerce std::initializer_list to container in templated function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I am not able to pass an initializer list to a templated function, to then call a non templated function which would coerce the initializer list to a container. However, when skipping the intermediate templated function, it compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyLoader {
    static auto load(const std::vector<int> &v) {
        return v;
    }
};

template<typename Loader, typename... Args>
auto makeVector(Args&&... args) {
    return Loader::load(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto v = makeVector<MyLoader>({ 8, 8, 8 });

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
}
```

Renders the error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'auto makeVector(Args&& ...) [with Loader = MyLoader; Args = {}]':
main.cpp:18:46:   required from here
main.cpp:13:24: error: no matching function for call to 'MyLoader::load()'
     return Loader::load(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:17: note: candidate: 'static auto MyLoader::load(const std::vector<int>&)'
     static auto load(const std::vector<int> &v) {
                 ^~~~
main.cpp:6:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:18:46: error: too many arguments to function 'auto makeVector(Args&& ...) [with Loader = MyLoader; Args = {}]'
     auto v = makeVector<MyLoader>({ 8, 8, 8 });
                                              ^
main.cpp:12:6: note: declared here
 auto makeVector(Args&&... args) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:18:10: error: 'void v' has incomplete type
     auto v = makeVector<MyLoader>({ 8, 8, 8 });
          ^
main.cpp:20:19: error: unable to deduce 'auto&&' from 'v'
     for (auto x : v) {
```

However the following compiles perfectly fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyLoader {
    static auto load(const std::vector<int> &v) {
        return v;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto v = MyLoader::load({ 8, 8, 8 });

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
}
```

Why is the initializer list not coerced to the `std::vector` argument of `MyLoader::load()` in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `{8, 8, 8}` isn't deducible as type.

If you pass it to a method that receive a `const std::vector<int>`, all goes well because the compiler know that `{8, 8, 8}` is used to initialize a `std::vector<int>`.

But if you pass it to a function that receive a variadic list (`Args&&... args`) of **unknown types** arguments, this doesn't works because the compiler doesn't know witch type is `{8, 8, 8}`.

Suggestion: pass the values in a variadic way

```
auto v = makeVector<MyLoader>(8, 8, 8);
```

so the compiler can detect `Args...` as `int, int, int`, and pass to `load()` adding graphs

```
// ------------------V-----------------------------V   
return Loader::load( { std::forward<Args>(args)... } );
```

If you really (really!) want to pass th values to `makeVector()` as initialization list, you can intercept they as an array

```
template <typename Ldr, std::size_t Dim, typename Arg>
auto makeVector (Arg(&&arg)[Dim])
```

So the compiler can deduce the type (`Arg`, as `int`) and the size (`Dim`, `3` in case of `{8, 8, 8}`.

But to unpack the array you need the indexes, so a function helper.

Something as

```
template <typename Ldr, std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t Dim, typename Arg>
auto makeVectorH (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, Arg(&&arg)[Dim])
 { return Ldr::load({std::forward<Arg>(arg[Is])...}); }

template <typename Ldr, std::size_t Dim, typename Arg>
auto makeVector (Arg(&&arg)[Dim])
 { return makeVectorH<Ldr>(std::make_index_sequence<Dim>{},
                           std::forward<Arg[Dim]>(arg)); }
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example for array case (but I suggest the simpler use of variadic arguments)

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct MyLoader
 { static auto load(const std::vector<int> &v) { return v; } };

template <typename Ldr, std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t Dim, typename Arg>
auto makeVectorH (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, Arg(&&arg)[Dim])
 { return Ldr::load({std::forward<Arg>(arg[Is])...}); }

template <typename Ldr, std::size_t Dim, typename Arg>
auto makeVector (Arg(&&arg)[Dim])
 { return makeVectorH<Ldr>(std::make_index_sequence<Dim>{},
                           std::forward<Arg[Dim]>(arg)); }

int main ()
 {
   auto v = makeVector<MyLoader>({8, 8, 8});

   for (auto x : v)
        std::cout << x << "\n";
 }
```

Comment: Why is `{ 8, 8, 8 }` not known to the compiler as `std::initializer_list<int>`?

Comment: @shane Because an "initializer list" (`{8, 8, 8}`) isn't an `std::initializer_list<>`. I mean: an "initializer list" is used to initialize a lot of types (`std::initializer_list` but also `std::vector`, `std::set`, etc.) but isn't a type itself; so can't be deduced as `std::initualizer_list` or `std::vector` or `std::set` (etc.).

Comment: The fact that `{ 8, 8, 8 }` is not a `std::initializer_list<>` is the detail I was missing! Thanks